# How to setup netbeans to compile sass on ubuntu?

Tags: sass, netbeans-7, compass-sass

i'm using netbeans 7.4 on ubuntu 12.04.I have ruby 1.8.7 install and gems for sass,compass and susy.
i would to setup netbeans to autocompile scss files on save.
i found 2 places to setup this:

`tools > options > Misc > scss` for netbeans general

and in project properties, preprocessors tab.

actually i have for my sass home : `/usr/local/bin/sass`
but i can't locate my gems folder.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bourbon (3.1.8)
chunky_png (1.2.9)
compass (0.12.2)
fssm (0.2.10)
neat (1.5.0)
sass (3.2.12)
susy (1.0.9)
thor (0.18.1)
```

i don't know about my PATH too (location,content..).

thanks

Comment: change sass home into netbeans to `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12`,version is recognized but after netbeans restart:
`Compile application.scss...
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- date (LoadError)
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:1
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:9:in `require'
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass.rb:9
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass.rb:1:in `require'
 from <script>:1

COMPILATION HAS FAILED.`